# geolocator flutter package not working on my real device honor 8x

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

Its perfectly working on my emulator and giving me longitude and latitude as an output but on my real device every time I press  the flat button I created to access the current location it's not giving me any output in the console and showing me this line again and again

**V/AudioManager( 9157): querySoundEffectsEnabled...**

Answer (score 0):

That seems odd.  You did perform all of https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#usage that's appropriate for your platform, yes?  But why "sound effects" comes into play?  You'll have to show more of your code.